# I have an error in my ListAdapter class constructors

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

This is the code:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this, jenres, pics);
```

`(alt + enter)` didn't help and it says "`ListAdapter()` in ListAdapter cannot be applied to:
expected    actual
parameteres arguments
!!

Comment: Post your ListAdapter code

Comment: it seems that `jenres` and/or `pics` are not the kind of objects which can passed to a `ListAdapter`

Comment: add your  adapter code to

Comment: @PradeepGupta how should i do that??

Answer (score 0):

Its because you donot have the required matching constructor in your ListAdapter class. Create the constructor as:

```
public ListAdapter(Context context, yourJenresType jenres, yourPicsType pics)  {
// do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main class, the signature:-

```
ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(Activityname.this, jenres, pics);
```

In your ListAdpater:-

```
public class ListAdapter extends YourAdapter{
Context context;
VariableType jenres;
VariableType pics;

//Constructor:

public ListAdapter(Context context, VariableType jenres, VariableType pics){
this.context= context;
this. jenres=jenres;
this.pics=pics;

}

//Adapter methods below
}
```

Comment: i add the Activityname.this an it still have error that says my listadapter class is not an enclosing class)

Comment: Change the name of your adatper to CustomListAdapter and try again